# Uniformly Continuous Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How can I show:

> Let  {$f_n$} be a sequence of functions that are uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$. Show if {$f_n$} converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $(0,1)$ then $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.

Comment: The problem does not state "uniformly continuous sequence." The quote is "functions that are uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$", which means that for any for any $f_n$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $|x - y| < \delta$. Note that the $\delta$ can depend on $n$ (if it does not, we have "equicontinuity")

Comment: It is not a "uniformly continuous sequence." It is a sequence of functions, each of each being [uniformly continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity) on $(0,1)$; sequence which [converges uniformly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence) to a function $f$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by uniformly continuous sequence. You have two concepts involved in the question: uniform continuity of functions, of which you have a sequence, and uniform convergence of a sequence. Perhaps you meant to ask what it means for a sequence of functions to converge uniformly on, say, $(0,1)$. Do you know the definition?

Comment: Thanks, I realize I just read that wrong.

Comment: Delete the first and third "uniformly."   Can you prove this version?  If not then there is the real source of your difficulty.  When you can, come back for another hint.